# Problems on definition of genus with multiplicative sequence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, modular-forms, cobordism

I’m reading *Manifolds and Modular Forms*.

According to its introduction chapter, the definition of genus is a ring homomorphism $\varphi:\Omega\otimes\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow R$ with $R$ an integral domain over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\Omega$ the cobordism ring.

But on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence?wprov=sfti1), the definition seems to be $\varphi:\Omega\rightarrow R$, so what role does ‘$\otimes\mathbb{Q}$’ plays in the prior def?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article describes the general notion of a genus, allowing for homomorphisms to general rings, for instance, to ${\mathbb Z}/2$. The authors of the book you are reading, prefer to work **over ${\mathbb Q}$**, i.e. when $R$ is a ${\mathbb Q}$-algebra, eliminating examples such as the ring ${\mathbb Z}/2$. Of course, one can still consider ring-homomorphisms
$$
\Omega\to R,
$$
but (if one thinks in terms of ${\mathbb Q}$-algebras) it is more natural to consider ${\mathbb Q}$-algebra homomorphisms
$$
\Omega \otimes {\mathbb Q}\to R.
$$
This is what your book does.

Comment: Thanks for that.